# Firefox select element doubles text-indent value

Tags: css, firefox

I discovered a strange issue today which seems to be a bug in Firefox 35.0. When specifying a `text-indent` property for a `select` element, Firefox seems to double the pixel value. Other browsers are correctly displaying the indent.

Is there a workaround to avoid this? I'm forced to use `text-indent` rather than `padding` to work around various other browser inconsistencies (specifically webkit on a Mac). I need to use `text-indent` but I'm unable to stop the value from doubling in Firefox.

Here's an example showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/k92dvxte/1/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Confirmed on Firefox 34.0.5

Comment: Any link to the bug report?

Comment: Try using a moz hack even i saw that issue , text-indent to 50px in firefox

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Explaining what @sydonia said:

You'll just have to put this code after the select rule in your CSS:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select {
       text-indent: 50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Expanding on this slightly with further explanation after my research: the `@document` at-query can be used with `url-prefix` to specifically target firefox as a hack. Typically `@document url-prefix()` can be used to apply specific CSS styles when the URL matches a prefix defined in `url-prefix()`. This hack uses the `@-moz-document` vendor prefix to specifically target Firefox and not other browsers. Leaving the url-prefix empty will match every URL.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document

Comment: @HerrSerker, yes, a handy workaround. I would welcome a real solution to fix it!

Comment: Just think of the situation when you change the value of the indent. You should remember to change the value for FF as well. Unless you have a calculated value made with a CSS preprocessor like LESS or SASS or similar.This is prone to errors.