# Is it possible to make text-indent property works only for chrome, safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have a combo box with a icon in the left hand. In chrome it looks like the second image overlapping icon and text -

So to resolve the problem I used text-indent because in chrome and safari browser don't consider padding.

Now the issue resolved in chrome and safari. But the problem is in firefox both padding and text-indent has considered. And it looks like -

[image]

[image]

To restrict firefox I wrote the css like -

```
.filter:not(*:root) {
    text-indent: 19px;
}
```

Still for firefox 53.0 its considering text-indent.

Any workaround for this problem ?

Comment: You **could try** `-webkit-text-indent: 19px;`

Comment: not working. invalid property value.

Comment: you can target only webkit browsers using a css hack

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812093/is-there-a-google-chrome-only-css-hack

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question:
[Firefox select element doubles text-indent value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108434/firefox-select-element-doubles-text-indent-value)

To reset the text-indent for firefox only:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select {
        text-indent: 0;
    }
}
```